# Retrieve MAX Primary Key values of all tables in a database at once

Tags: mysql, database

What I need to do is retrieve the maximum primary key of all tables in my database **at once**? That is, my result will be like if I executed the below 2 queries:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM DATABASE_NAME

SELECT MAX(PRIMARY_KEY) AS maxId FROM TABLE
```

That is

```
(first column = TableName , second column = MAX(PK) Of that table)
```

Pardon if I am doing something wrong. I just do not want to write 80 queries because my database has 80 tables.

Comment: This sounds like a classical case of fixation. What are you ***really*** trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Perception i am migrating from Windows to Linux so i need this for that.

Comment: What does moving from one OS to another have to do with primary keys exactly? You are probably reinventing the wheel here, can you give us more details because if it is what it seems it is - there are other methods.

Comment: we have stopped our database now so its for delta recovery

Comment: I'm still puzzled why you wouldn't use replication or simple mysqldump..

Comment: I don't know what @FawadGhafoor is using this for, but this is useful if you want to monitor whether you're getting close to overflowing any primary key columns in your database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If (and only if) your primary keys are `AUTO INCREMENT` variables you can do this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM   information_schema.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb'
```

Comment: lets say my db name is "thanks" than Unknown column 'thanks' in 'where clause'

Comment: @FawadGhafoor you have to put the table name in quotes - it's a string.

Comment: @FawadGhafoor sorry, I confused "table name" / "database name" - that last parameter is the _database name_, and the query will return one row for each _table_.

Comment: @FawadGhafoor so ask for `AUTO_INCREMENT - 1` in the `SELECT` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to the situation below when choosing the method of retrieving that info and what you are going to do with it:

AUTO_INCREMENT value is stored in memory, so after a server restart, AUTO_INCREMENT value is reset to:

```
SELECT MAX(ai_col) FROM table_name FOR UPDATE;
```

This can break things if the database has missing FKs and, for example, you delete some rows that refer to other tables. You would end up by reusing the same id.

Refer to: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-initialization

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type, extra
    FROM  `columns`
    WHERE  table_schema = 'mydb'
      AND  extra LIKE '%auto_increment%'
```

Optionally `JOIN` this with Alnitak's Answer.